# Substring after last dot

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

In my MySQL I have a table `user`. There's an `email` field.

Some emails have many dots in them, e.g.: `firstname.lastname.smth.else@example.com`

I'd like to select everything after last dot. In case of the email above it'll be `com`.

So far I've came up only with:

```
 SELECT RIGHT(email, LOCATE('.', email) - 1) FROM user;
```

but it seems to trim only after the first dot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(email, '.', -1) as suffix
from user;
```